# How to make vertical multi-column heading above the column heading

Tags: tables

How to make vertical multi-column heading above the column heading? i.e., simialar to the following figure?

[image]

Comment: Could you post a code of what you've tried, so we don't have to type everything from scratch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create new labels (here: `\rotLabel`) and define a angle (here: `45`) to orientate the labels with `\rotatebox`. Use `\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]` for columnswidth.

To draw a solid colored circle: `\newcommand{\filledcirc}{${\color{black}\bullet}\mathllap{\circ}$}`
or not colored: `\newcommand{\normalcirc}{${\color{white}\bullet}\mathllap{\circ}$}`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\zerobox}[2][l]{%
\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][#1]{#2}}
}
\newcommand*{\anglelabel}[1]{%
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\rotatebox{45}{\zerobox{#1}}}%
}
\newcommand*{\rotLabel}[1]{%
\anglelabel{\zerobox{#1}}
}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\filledcirc}{${\color{black}\bullet}\mathllap{\circ}$}
\newcommand{\normalcirc}{${\color{white}\bullet}\mathllap{\circ}$}
\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{|lllllllll|}
 \rotLabel{Detects MITM}
& \rotLabel{Detects Local MITM}
& \rotLabel{Protects Client Credential} 
& \rotLabel{Updatable Pins}
& \rotLabel{Detects TLS Stripping}
& \rotLabel{Affirms POST-to-HTTPS}
& \rotLabel{Responsive Revocation}
& \rotLabel{Intermediate CAs Visible}
\\
\hline
\multicolumn{9}{|c|}{\textit{Security Properties Offered}}\\
 &  &  &  & & & & &\\
 \hline
\normalcirc & \normalcirc & \normalcirc &  & & & & &\\
\normalcirc & \normalcirc & \normalcirc &  & & & & &\\
\filledcirc & \filledcirc & \filledcirc & \filledcirc & & & & &\\
\filledcirc & \filledcirc & \filledcirc & \filledcirc & & & & &\\
 & \filledcirc &  & \filledcirc & & & & &\\
 &  & \normalcirc & & & & & &\\
 &  & \normalcirc & & & & & &\\
 &  &  & \filledcirc & & & & &\\
\hline
 &  &  & &\normalcirc &\normalcirc & & &\\
 &  &  & \filledcirc &\filledcirc & \filledcirc & & &\\
 &  &  & \filledcirc &\filledcirc & \filledcirc & & &\\
 &  &  &  & & \filledcirc & & &\\
 \hline
  &  &  &  & & & \filledcirc & &\\
  &  &  &  & & & \filledcirc & &\\
  &  &  &  & & & \filledcirc & &\\
  &  &  &  & & & \filledcirc & \filledcirc & \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```